# Struct inside struct Equatable count duplicate item Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, struct, swift5, equatable

The answer I found is with one level of struct. In my code I want to find out how many same dates is in inside of the struct of the struct. I never use equatable before so I'm not sure how to implement it with struct inside struct.

I'm using Charts pod and the array `chartMetricItemSets` contains different readings with multiples days. ex: `["name": sugar, [["date": "Oct 10", "value": 120], ["date": "Oct 10", "value": 121], ["date": "Oct 11", "value": 120], ["date": "Oct 13", "value": 120], ["date": "Oct 13", "value": 121]]`. The `xAxisDates` will be `["Oct 10", "Oct 11", "Oct 13"]`

the x is the date and the y is for the same date sums

Goal: chartDataEntries should append `[x:0(10/10), y:241], [x:1(10/11), y:120], [x:2(10/13), y: 241]`

Thank you!

```
struct ChartData {
   let name: String
   let value: [ChartValue]
}

struct ChartValue {
    let date: Date
    let value: Double
 }

var chartMetricItemSets = [[ChartData]]()
var xAxisDates = [String]() //date array

func getChartDataSets() {
    for (index, chartHealthItemSet) in chartMetricItemSets.enumerated() {
        let dataSourceSelected = dataSourcesSelected[index]
        var chartDataEntries = [ChartDataEntry]() //array display on graph
        var chartYaxis: Double = 0
        var datePoint: Int = 0
        var countChartYaxis = 0
        var duplicateDateCount = 0

        for (index, item) in chartHealthItemSet[0].value.enumerated() {
            for (dateIndex, date) in xAxisDates.enumerated() {
                if item.date.convertDateToString(dateFormat: .monthDay) == date {
                    chartYaxis += item.value
                    datePoint = dateIndex
                    chartYaxis += 1
                    break
                }

                //missing counting duplicateDateCount 

                if duplicateDateCount == countChartYaxis {
                    chartDataEntries.append(ChartDataEntry(x: Double(datePoint), y: chartYaxis.roundUpNDecimal(n: 2)))
                }
            }
            print("chartYaxis: \(chartYaxis)")
            print("chartDataEntries: \(chartDataEntries)")
        }
        chartDataEntries.sort(by: { $0.x < $1.x })

        let set = LineChartDataSet(entries: chartDataEntries,
                                   label: HEALTH_TABLE.allCases[dataSourceSelected].info.name)

        set.mode = .linear // cubic line effect (smoother)
        set.colors = [HEALTH_TABLE.allCases[dataSourceSelected].info.chartColor]
        set.setCircleColor(.black)
        set.lineWidth = 1.5
        set.circleRadius = 3
        set.drawCircleHoleEnabled = false
        set.drawCirclesEnabled = true
        set.drawHorizontalHighlightIndicatorEnabled = true

        lineChartData?.addDataSet(set)
    }

    chartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: xAxisDates)
    chartView.xAxis.granularity = 1
    chartView.xAxis.axisMinLabels = 4
    chartView.xAxis.axisMaxLabels = 6

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.chartView.data = self.lineChartData
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 4 a useful API was introduced to group arrays to dictionaries by an arbitrary predicate.

You can group `chartHealthItemSet[0]`

```
let grouped = Dictionary(grouping: chartHealthItemSet[0], by: {$0.date.convertDateToString(dateFormat: .monthDay)}
```

The result is `["10/10":[ChartData], "10/11":[ChartData], ...]`

Sort the keys and assign them to `xAxisDates`

```
xAxisDates = grouped.keys.sorted()
```

To get the sum of the values get the array from the grouped dictionary for the date key, map it to the values and sum them up

```
for (index, date) in xAxisDates.enumerated() {
    let sum = grouped[date]!.map{$0.value}.reduce{0.0, +}
    chartDataEntries.append(ChartDataEntry(x: Double(index), y: sum.roundUpNDecimal(n: 2)))
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for answering but I got "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" error when I type out the first line. let grouped = ....

Comment: I got it! After changing a little bit :) Thank you so much!!